# noUiSlider prefix is not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, slider, currency, prefix, nouislider

So I am using a noUiSlider for price selection. The handle values have a currency prefix, so I need to update it if a customer changes currency, naturally.

Here's my code:

```
priceSlider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
  range: {
    min: minPrice,
    max: maxPrice
  },
  format: wNumb({ decimals: 0, prefix: currency })
})
```

Curiously, the range is being updated just fine, but the prefix is not being updated correctly. Is there something else I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: You can only change the 'margin', 'limit', 'step', 'range', 'animate' and 'snap' with updateOptions. https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/

Comment: @dmoo So is the only way to destroy the slider and create a new one? Seems like overkill just to update a prefix. Do you know if there is some way of querying the current prefix (so I can compare it to the new prefix and see if I need to destroy or not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
// Old prefix is different to new prefix, must destroy slider entirely
if ((priceSlider.noUiSlider.get()).charAt(0) != currency) {

  priceSlider.noUiSlider.destroy()
  // Create new slider here

} else {

  // Old prefix is identical, just do a regular update
  coursePriceSlider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
    // options here
  })

}
```